# Select não aparecendo no materialize

Tags: css

Estou tentando fazer um projeto aqui utilizando o Materialize, porém o campo *select* não está aparecendo.

Esse aqui é o HTML

```
<div class="input-field col s4">
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha uma opção</option>
      <option value="1">Código</option>
      <option value="2">Nome</option>
      <option value="3">Email</option>
    </select>
    <label for="search">Filtrar</label>
  </div>
```

Esse aqui é o JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('select').formSelect();});
```

Esta ficando assim na View

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quem quiser saber mais sobre tem uma documentação do Materialize: https://materializecss.com/select.html

Este ta sendo o erro do console

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Algum erro no console?

Comment: Vitor eu testei os Selects aqui nas duas versões do Materialize e não deu nenhum erro no Console, o JS está certinho. Se acusou algum erro deve ser pq tem algo a mais no seu Script que está acusando o erro. Até pq usei a documentação oficial, e não inclui nada a mais no script. Então o erro é algo não relacionado com o Script do Select.. Vc tem que ver o que vc fez a de JS

Comment: Ele esta me mostrando erro de $ indefinida

Comment: É eu reparei, mas não é relacionado ao script do Select, esse erro é em outra parte do seu JS, vc deve ter colocado algo a mais ai nesse script. Te aconselho a abrir outra pergunta e colocar o seu JS completo para ver o que pode ser... Tanto que se vc testar só com o código que eu postei em um arquivo novo vc vai ver que não da nenhum erro no console.

Comment: agora deu outro erro: Uncaught ReferenceError: Materialize is not defined

Comment: Esse é o script que eu usei `$('select').formSelect();` repare que nele nem aparece a palavra "Materialize"... Seu erro não é com o Select. É em outra parte do script. Como e falei te recomento abrir outra pergunta, colocar seu JavaScript completo e algum usuário vai poder te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Ok entao, vou estar abrindo outra pergunta, Obrigado hugocsl

Comment: @hugocsl se tiver interesse, entre la na outra questao https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/302516/erro-uncaught-referenceerror-materialize-is-not-defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara seu problema é que vc está usando uma versão do Materialize, mas está usando o `script` de outra versão. *Recentemente o Mateiralize sofreu uma atualização de versão passando da `0.100.2` para `1.0.0-rc-1`* Link da documentação dessa versão http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/forms.html#select-initialization

Para aversão **`0.100.2`** use dessa forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').material_select();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s4">
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha uma opção</option>
            <option value="1">Código</option>
            <option value="2">Nome</option>
            <option value="3">Email</option>
        </select>
        <label for="search">Filtrar</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Para aversão **`1.0.0-rc-1`** use dessa forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s4">
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha uma opção</option>
            <option value="1">Código</option>
            <option value="2">Nome</option>
            <option value="3">Email</option>
        </select>
        <label for="search">Filtrar</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, vou estar testando aqui

Comment: Jaja te dou um retorno

Comment: @VictorGabriel Resumindo o que falei vc está usando uma versão do Materialize, mas está iniciando o Select com o script da outra versão... QQ coisa da o toque

Comment: Estou tentando e deu uma deformada na minha view

Comment: postei ai como ficou @hugocsl

Comment: @VictorGabriel Cara eu vi, estenho esse tipo de bug. Pois teoricamente só mudou a inicialização do Select... Vou editer a minha resposta e colocar a opção para as duas versões acho que vai ficar melhor

Comment: vlw cara, estou no aguardo

Comment: @VictorGabriel cara dei uma editada na resposta, repare que agora tem as duas opções para as duas versões. Repare também que o Select tem que se encaixar no seu grid no número de colunas etc. Se o número de colunas dentro da Row somar mais de 12, vc pode ter problemas de quebra de layout. No mais vc está no caminho certo, consultando a documentação oficial. Só se atente nas versões e não misture códigos de uma na outra.

Comment: Obrigado Hugo, vou estar testando

Comment: tentei e ficou do msm jeito

Comment: o console esta mostrando um erro

Comment: Editei a publicação...quando puder olhe la para observar este erro

Comment: @VictorGabriel quanl versão afinal vc está usando a 1.0.0 ou a 0.100.2 ??

Comment: 1.0.0 beta: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js