# Erro Uncaught ReferenceError: Materialize is not defined

Tags: javascript, materialize

Eea galera td bem? Estou desenvolvendo um projeto com Materialize e neste projeto esta dando erro no JS, podem me ajudar? Estarei colocando o código a seguir:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://demo.expertphp.in/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://demo.expertphp.in/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  Materialize.updateTextFields();
  $('.sidenav').sidenav();
  $('.fixed-action-btn').floatingActionButton();
  $('select').formSelect();

});
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-action-btn');
   var instances = M.FloatingActionButton.init(elems, {
     direction: 'top',
     hoverEnabled: false
   });
   });
```

Comment: No seu exemplo dá o erro *Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined*, pois está importando o Materialize antes do jQuery, sendo que o segundo é requisito do primeiro.

Comment: Insira o jquery primeiro.

Comment: nada ainda, n esta funcionando

Comment: A partir da versão 1.0 alpha, o jQuery não é mais uma dependência, esse é um dos motivos de eu utilizar o Materialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Victor, vc certamente está consultando a versão errada da documentação. Na verdade vc está novamente utilizando uma versão do Materialize e chamando os Scripts da versão antiga!

Veja que esse é o link da documentação antiga [Prefilling Text Inputs Antigo](http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/forms.html)

Mas se vc está usando a versão **1.0.0-rc1** então vc precisa da documentação desse link  **[Prefilling Text Inputs NOVO](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html)**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    M.updateTextFields();
  });
```

Então **não** use o  `Materialize.updateTextFields();` use no lugar dele o

```
M.updateTextFields(); // opção correta!
```

Comment: hugo FOI!! kkkkk muito obrigado cara, vou prestar mais atencao nas documentacoes agr, desculpa o incomodo

Comment: @VictorGabriel tranquilo jovem, a versão nova do Materialize saiu tem pouco tempo, então é comum pesquisar no Google e cair no Link antigo. Preste atenção tb no Bootstrap que costuma dar o mesmo problema. []´s

Comment: obrigado cara, eu estava precisando tambem tirar um duvida, tem problema me mandar um email para conversarmos melhor?

Comment: @VictorGabriel sempre que fizer uma pergunta e tiver uma resposta que te atende considere marca-la como aceita clicando no `✔` ao lado das setas da resposta que escolher. Não sei exatamente se vou poder te ajudar. Mas vai postando usas perguntas aqui pq se eu não pder te ajudar sempre tem alguém com mais conhecimento que vai poder.

Comment: Obrigado Hugo, poderia estar me ajudando com uma duvida? Enviarei o link aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/302819/como-deixar-o-return-do-sql-object-laravel

Comment: @VictorGabriel vixi cara, nessa não consigo te ajudar, não sei nada de back-end, sql, laravel etc nunca nem mexi...

Comment: ah sim, blz muito obg vc é front-end entao?

Comment: @VictorGabriel na verdade sou designe, e mexo um pouco com web. Entendo mais de CSS, HTML e um pouquinho quase nada de jQuery

Comment: pode me passar seu linkedin?

Comment: @VictorGabriel https://www.linkedin.com/in/hugo-lima-bb145638/

Comment: preciso do email

Comment: @VictorGabriel hugocsl@gmail.com